# Measurability of infimum function

Tags: measure-theory, calculus-of-variations, measurable-functions

In Theorem 14.37 of Variational Analysis by Rockafellar and Wets, it shows that for any normal integrand $f:T\times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the function $p:T\to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$p(t):=\inf f(t,⋅)$
is measurable. I am struggling to understand a step of the proof. In particular, it says that, since the closure correspondence:
$$
\text{Cl}R:t\mapsto \left\lbrace \alpha\in \mathbb{R}:p(t)\leq \alpha\right\rbrace
$$
is closed-valued and measurable, then $p$ is measurable.

Comment: I don't have the book. What is $T$ and what is a normal integrand?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have made a more precise answer. $(T,\mathcal{F})$ is an arbitrary measurable space, while a normal integrand is a function whose epigraphical correspondence is closed-valued and measurable. In particular,  $f:T\times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a normal integrand, if the correspondence: $\Gamma_f:t\mapsto \left\lbrace (x,\alpha)\in \mathbb{R}^2:f(t,x)\leq \alpha\right\rbrace$ is closed-valued and measurable.

Comment: @Giuliosky Just rewrite the question making all definitions and terms used clear. Adding explanations in comments is not a good idea since the question itself should be self-contained.